# How can I store the previous all the values of my state in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state, react-typescript

I have 2 objects size and colors later it will be more. I have a dynamic field based on those attributes. The problem is I can store the first field values but when I add the second dynamic field the previous data is removed.  I am trying to store all the previous data values when the state update.

If you wish, you can see my live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-http-0yh6m3?file=/src/App.js

My states and data: addAttributes for showing values and fakeAttributes are the detailed value of addAttributes.

```
const [attributes, setAttributes] = useState([{ label: '', value: 1 }])
const [newAttributes, setNewAttributes] = useState([{ label: '', value: 1 }])

// Data
 const addAttributes = [
        { label: 'colors', value: 1 },
        { label: 'size', value: 2 },
    ]

    // Attributes data

    const fakeAttributes = [{
        label: 'colors',
        object: [
            { label: 'Black', value: 1 },
            { label: 'Green', value: 2 },
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'size',
        object: [
            { label: 'M', value: 1 },
            { label: 'S', value: 2 },
        ]
    }
    ]
```

I am using react-select npm, The below code is adding a dynamic field. `setNewAttributes` storing the values into the `newAttributes` state. When I `console.log(newAttributes)` it returns the value correctly but **as soon as I add a new field the previous data removing**. I didn't create any function for adding dynamic fields I have tried this way.

```
{fakeAttributes.map((attr) => {
    const item = attributes.filter((list) => {
        return list.label === attr.label;
    })[0];
    if (item) {

        return <div key={attr.label} className="basis-1/4">
            <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> {attr.label} </label>
            <Select options={attr.object} onChange={(e: any) => setNewAttributes(e)} className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" isMulti /></div>
    }
})}
```

**I have tried like this way, If I use dependency it calls the value every time but did not work properly:**

```
  useEffect(() =>{
        setNewAttributes((oldArray):any => [...oldArray, newAttributes]);
    }, [newAttributes])
```

My expected result is similar to this array object.

```
[
0:{label: 'colors', SelectedValue: {{label: "green"}}, 
1:{label: 'size', SelectedValue: {{label: "M"}, {label: "S"}}
]
```

My full code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "file-upload-with-preview/dist/file-upload-with-preview.min.css";
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';
import Select from 'react-select';
import './AddProduct.css'
import AddRemoveMultipleInputFields from './AddRemoveMultipleInputFields';


interface IAppProps {

}

const AddProduct: React.FunctionComponent<IAppProps> = (props) => {
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())
const [size, setSize] = useState()
const [attributes, setAttributes] = useState([{ label: '', value: 1 }])
const [newAttributes, setNewAttributes] = useState([{ label: '', value: 1 }])
const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState([]);
// const [arr, setArr] = useState([])



const onSelectFile = (event: any) => {
const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
const selectedFilesArray = Array.from(selectedFiles);

const imagesArray: any = selectedFilesArray.map((file: any) => {
return URL.createObjectURL(file);
});

setSelectedImages((previousImages) => previousImages.concat(imagesArray));
};

// Data need to break and store label info in another variable and add value dynamically
const addAttributes = [
{ label: 'colors', value: 1 },
{ label: 'size', value: 2 },
]

// Attributes data
const fakeAttributes = [{
label: 'colors',
object: [
{ label: 'Black', value: 1 },
{ label: 'Green', value: 2 },
]
},
{
label: 'size',
object: [
{ label: 'M', value: 3 },
{ label: 'S', value: 4 },
]
}
]
useEffect(() =>{
setNewAttributes((oldArray): any => [...oldArray, ...attributes]);
},[])

// const previousValue = () => {
//     setNewAttributes((oldArray): any => [...oldArray, ...attributes]);
// }
// console.log(newAttributes);


const Countries = [
{ label: "M", value: 355 },
{ label: "S", value: 54 },
{ label: "XL", value: 43 },
{ label: "XXL", value: 61 },
];



return (
<div className=" ">
<div className="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
<form action="#" method="POST">
<div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">

<div className="col-span-2">
    <div className="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
        <div className="px-4 py-5 bg-white space-y-6 sm:p-6">
            {/* TITLE */}
            <div>
                <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> Title </label>
                <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Title" />
            </div>
            {/* SHORT DETAILS */}
            <div className="flex flex-row gap-6">
                <div className="basis-1/2">
                    <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> Brand </label>
                    <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Brand " required />

                </div>

                <div className="basis-1/2">
                    <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> Categories </label>
                    <Select onChange={(e: any) => setSize(e)} className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" options={Countries} isMulti />
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row gap-6">
                <div className="basis-1/4">
                    <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> Regular Price </label>
                    <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Regular Price " required />

                </div>
                <div className="basis-1/4">
                    <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> Sale Price </label>
                    <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Sale Price" />

                </div>
                <div className="basis-1/4">
                    <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> Offer last date and time </label>
                    <DateTimePicker className='shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline' onChange={setDate} value={date} />
                </div>



            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-row gap-6'>


{fakeAttributes.map((attr) => {
const item = attributes.filter((list) => {
return list.label === attr.label;
})[0];
if (item) {

return <div key={attr.label} className="basis-1/4">
<label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> {attr.label} </label>
<Select options={attr.object} onChange={(e: any) => setNewAttributes(e)} className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" isMulti /></div>
}
})}




            </div>

            <div>
                <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> Description </label>
                <textarea className="shadow form-textarea mt-1 block w-full border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" rows={5} placeholder="Description"></textarea>
            </div>



        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div className="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden bg-white px-4 py-5 bg-white space-y-6 sm:p-6">
    <section className='image-upload'>
        <label className='mt-1 flex justify-center px-6 pt-5 pb-6 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-md flex-col items-center '>
            <div>
                <svg className="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-gray-400" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 48 48" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path d="M28 8H12a4 4 0 00-4 4v20m32-12v8m0 0v8a4 4 0 01-4 4H12a4 4 0 01-4-4v-4m32-4l-3.172-3.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0L28 28M8 32l9.172-9.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L28 28m0 0l4 4m4-24h8m-4-4v8m-12 4h.02" strokeWidth="2" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" />
                </svg>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <span>+ Add Images up to 10 images</span>
                <input
                    type="file"
                    name="images"
                    onChange={onSelectFile}
                    multiple
                    accept="image/png , image/jpeg, image/webp"
                />
            </div>
        </label>

        <br />

        {selectedImages.length > 0 &&
            (selectedImages.length > 10 ? (
                <p className="error">
                    You can't upload more than 10 images! <br />
                    <span>
                        please delete <b> {selectedImages.length - 10} </b> of them{" "}
                    </span>
                </p>
            ) : (
                ''
            ))}

        <div className="images flex flex-row gap-6">
            {selectedImages &&
                selectedImages.map((image, index) => {
                    return (

                        <div key={image} className="image basis-1/4">
                            <div className='flex justify-between'>
                                <button
                                    onClick={() =>
                                        setSelectedImages(selectedImages.filter((e) => e !== image))
                                    }
                                >
                                    x
                                </button>
                                <p>{index + 1}</p>
                            </div>
                            <img className='shadow sm:rounded-md' src={image} height="200" alt="upload" />


                        </div>


                    );
                })}
        </div>
    </section>
    <div className="basis-1/4">

        <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-3"> Attributes </label>
        <Select onChange={(e: any) => setAttributes(e)} className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" options={addAttributes} isMulti />

    </div>

    <div className=" py-3 text-right ">
        <button  type="submit" className="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent drop-shadow-md text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Publish</button>
    </div>
</div>


</div>
</form>
</div>

</div>

)
};

export default AddProduct;
```

Comment: Could you please include how expected result needs to be?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan The expected result should be similar to this:  `[{label: 'colors', SelectedValue: {{label: "green"}}, {label: 'size', SelectedValue: {{label: "M"}, {label: "S"}}]`